# Indentify escape keywords and block in java

Tags: java, algorithm, jakarta-ee

I have a query which hits a java application (SOLR).

One particular pattern of the query comes like

```
http:server:port/app/select?q=(skunum:(2809553163000\+OR+09552883000\+OR+09553124000\))
```

If you notice at the end of each and every item numbers there is an escape character.

I need to block this type of queries from hitting my app.

I just need to know how to identify these particular queries? Is there any pattern match clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that fundamentally the problem is determining whether a string (the URL query string, in this case) contains any of a set of characters (the escaped characters). I can think of two approaches. One is to use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum):

```
// ignore queries containing a, b, or c in the query string
if (url.getQuery().matches("[abc]"))
{
    // ignore query
}
```

Another is to use a function that iterates over a string looking for characters from a given set. I found a `bool ContainsAny(String, char[])` example method [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ChecksiftheStringcontainsanycharacterinthegivensetofcharacters.htm). The regular expression is a more general solution (and a bit trickier to use, especially for novices), but the `ContainsAny()` method is also sufficient in this case.

A bigger issue is input validation. This is important not only for proper application function but also for security. By all means take any steps you can to ensure that all queries you process match your specifications and contain values that make sense. Look for APIs provided by Java or SOLR to facilitate this.

One final point: in the example you provide, it is not clear to me that there are true "escapes" present in it. I see backslashes (`\`) after each number, but these are not necessarily escapes, as the characters that follow (`+` and `)`) do not need to be escaped. In fact, spaces in URLs are often mapped to the `+` character, or `%20`.